# Facebook emdedded Join Group button - Redirect on action

Tags: javascript, facebook, redirect, join

I have added a Facebook Join Group button to my sales funnel using the generated code that FB provides. It works great:

- You have a script element with a Join Group button.
- Once you click the button it brings up the pop-up in which you can confirm to Join this group.
- Once you confirm the pop-up closes and the Join Group button text on a webpage refreshes and changes to Pending

On this event (when somebody joins the group) I would like to redirect a visitor to next funnel step (new URL).

```
<!-- FB Join Group JS code -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.1&appId=[app-id-number]&autoLogAppEvents=1';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<!-- Display Button Code -->
<div class="fb-group" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/[fb-group-id]/" data-width="280" data-show-social-context="false" data-show-metadata="false"></div>
```

Does anybody know how can I catch the Join event with JS and redirect to new URL?

Comment: You can't. You are not allowed to incentivize the user for joining your group.

Comment: I believe that now you can do that. I have copied the code from FB last week and I have it on my page and it works. People can join the group right from my page (tested). I just don't know how to redirect them after they join.

You can check out the implementation here:
https://teamphoenix-academy.com/one-step-to-go

Comment: I'm saying that is the part that is not possible. You can have a button but it will not tell you if the user joined or not because that means that you can force the user to join your group before you let them do something else

Comment: OK now I understand, thanks!